# Let's encrypt certification does not work for nginx on ubuntu

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt

I am getting the following error when running sudo certbot-auto --nginx. I followed the instructions in this website https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuother-nginx using nginx and Ubuntu 14

```
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem") 
failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\nnginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen(\'/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem\',\'r\') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n',)
```

I also do not understand the python warning since

```
python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

but for any reason it uses python 2

Also it might be useful to know that there are no certicates available right now

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --nginx
/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.

nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

The nginx plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: MisconfigurationError('Error while running nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t.\n\nnginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen(\'/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.benty-fields.com/fullchain.pem\',\'r\') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)\nnginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed\n',)
```

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it...

one has to remove the certbot links in a few files which can be found with

```
grep -R /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem /etc/nginx/
```